# How to use proxy for R?

Tags: r, api, google-maps, proxy

I want to use google api, but in some country like China
we are not free to connect google, especially in R using API
so we need a way to do that

after several hours try, I finally could make it.
In order to help others go through the hardest part

I will post my answer below

Comment: my `googleway` package provides access to Google's APIs, and you should be able to pass in a proxy as [per the issues identified here](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/26). For the directions and distance API you can use the CRAN release. For the other APIs you'll need to use the development version on github.

Comment: I knew that googleway API, but thanks anyway~

Comment: Hi Symbolix: when I try to use the method googlenearestRoads, I always got an error:Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 403. Do you know what happened？and how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Are you using the development version of the package from github, or the one from CRAN?

Comment: the one from CRAN

Comment: Please try the development one, as the CRAN one doesn't have the proxy argument on the functions yet. The details are in the thread in the link I provided.

Comment: OK,actually I wrote the interface myself due to need in work, will give a try later, and will feed you back if there is sth I want to notice you, Thanks!

Comment: The one in github dev helps, please load it to CRAN, that one not working, I believe it has some problem regarding the json operation

Comment: I plan on releasing it to CRAN soon, but am working on a few other updates to the package as well.

Comment: OK,by the way, do you know anyway to find the closest highway or highway exit/entrance, either in your package or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proxy_url <- "http://127.0.0.1:61387/"
Sys.setenv(http_proxy = proxy_url, https_proxy = proxy_url, ftp_proxy = proxy_url)
```

you only need to record your proxy url and tell R by setting and you are all set, I believe it works for all people have restriction on their internet

cheers~~